# How to listen the key pressed on all the document using JavaScript and Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, listener, keypress

I have founded that if I want to listen on all the document I should do :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(e.keyCode);
             if (e.keyCode == 27) {
               $('#tftextinput').value="";
               $('#tfbutton').click();
            }
});
```

but it doesn't write anything in the console... So I have tried an other version like this:

```
$(".container.body").keydown(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(e.keyCode);
             if (e.keyCode == 27) {
               $('#tftextinput').value="";
               $('#tfbutton').click();
            }
 });
```

this code is in the `$(document).ready(function() {});`

but nothing happened too...

[image]

EDIT:

If I write this code in the web console it works:
[image]

So why it doesn't work in my Meteor template code ?

```
Template.home.onRendered(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        this method listen if we press "enter" in the research field and click on the button
        */
        $('#tftextinput').keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $('#tfbutton').click();
            }
        });
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(e.keyCode);
             if (e.keyCode == 27) {
               $('#tftextinput').value="";
               $('#tfbutton').click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the first listener works (the one who listens `tftextinput`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on window

```
$(window).on("keydown",function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(e.keyCode);
             if (e.keyCode == 27) {
               $('#tftextinput').value="";
               $('#tfbutton').click();
            }
 });
```

Comment: finally it works, I just had to put it on an other place thank you !

Comment: Just keep in mind that this code won't clear by itself automatically. So if you have this in `onRendered` callback it will attach "keydown" event listener every time you render that template. Say you navigate back and forth and template gets rendered 5 times so you'll end up having 5 keydown handlers attached to window object. I'd advocate for going with template-level helpers or if you really need to attach event listener to `window` then do clean up in a onDestroyed callback: `Template.home.onDestroyed(function(){ $(window).off("keydown") })`

Answer (score 2):

You could use Template events to do the same:

```
Template.home.events({
   'keydown':function(event){
       ...
   },
   'keypress #tftextinput': function(event){
       ...
   }
});
```

Comment: This is the best Meteor answer.